# Line-Height affecting text alignment with images negative margin after image has too much coverage

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to align text with a `line-height` of `2.0` to the top of images visually.

The issue I am having is when the images are in an anchor tag and center aligned the applied negative margin is too small and unwanted. As CSS standards do not support `has()` what is the best way to only give negative margin to paragraphs and headers that immediately follow left or right aligned images that are contained in a anchor?

I could use Javascript to add a class to the HTML in the DOM to specify that the `a` "contains a left aligned image". However I would like to use only CSS if there is a proper solution.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ntwysnq2/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="example1 clearfix">
<a><img class="left" src="//placehold.it/500x500/" width="100" /></a>
<p>
This is correct. example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 example1 
</p>
</div>

<div class="example2 clearfix">
<a><img class="center" src="//placehold.it/500x500/" width="100" /></a>
<p>
This is <em>not</em> correct. example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 example2 
</p>
</div>

<div class="example3 clearfix">
<img class="left" src="//placehold.it/500x500/" width="100" />
<p>
This is correct. example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 example3 
</p>
</div>

<div class="example4 clearfix">
<img class="center" src="//placehold.it/500x500/" width="100" />
<p>
This is correct. example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 example4 
</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .clearfix:before, 
    .clearfix:after {
        content: " ";
        display: table;
    }
    .clearfix:after {
        clear: both;
    }

p {line-height:2.0;}
img.left {float:left;}

    img.left + p,
    a + p {
        margin-top:-.5em;
    }
    img.left + h2,
    a + h2{
        margin-top:-.1em;
    }
    img.left + h3,
    a + h3 {
        margin-top:-.5em;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a rule that resets the margin for those cases like:

```
a .center {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Or, you could move the classes to the links and rewrite the rules like this:

```
.left {
  float: left;
}

.left + p {
  margin-top: -.5em;
}

.left + h2 {
  margin-top: -.1em;
}

.left + h3 {
  margin-top: -.5em;
}
```

For the last option: https://jsfiddle.net/ntwysnq2/4/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! As long as keeping the classes on the images instead of the links is semantic I'm going to go with a slightly modified version of your top suggestion.

`.clearfix a img:not(.left):not(.right) {margin-bottom: 1em;}` The clearfix is to limit it to areas that have content and keep it from images in the header that are already aligned.